# Excel Formula - Check if cell has formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

What formula do you use to check if another cell has formula? For example, I have 2 columns, A has cells which contains either a formula or a value.

(Column A usually contains Formulas but other users try to change their values by directly typing and replacing the formula that was previously there)

In Column B I want to add a formula that will say "HasFormula" if the cell on Column A has formula and say "PlainValue" if it contains a value.

I'm thinking maybe using `=ISNUMBER()` but that may not be accurate.

I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: Not what you are looking for but have you played with `Ctrl`+` ? That's Ctrl together with the 'back-tick' (lower case tilde).

Answer (score 9):

Excel actually has a builtin `ISFORMULA()` function.

Say `A1` has a formula and you want to check that. In say `B1`, you can use:

`=If(ISFORMULA(A1),"HasFormula","PlainValue")`

Edit: Per your comment, you don't have `ISFORMULA()`. An alternative is to create a quick UDF, and use the custom function in the worksheet.

In a workbook module, put this code:

```
Function isFormula(ByVal target As Range) As Boolean
     isFormula = target.hasFormula
End Function
```

Then you can call it like this: `=isFormula(A1)` and it will return `TRUE` if `A1` has a formula.

If you can't use VBA, then you can use this formula:
`=IF(ISERROR(FORMULATEXT(A1)),"PlainText","HasFormula")`

Comment: I saw similar post on the net but my Excel 2010 doesn't seem to have that built-in formula. I get a `#NAME?` no matter what.

Comment: @jay - Are you open to a VBA option? I edited the post with a quick UDF that would do the same as `ISFORMULA()`.

Comment: It is good practice to mention that the function (e.g. `ISFORMULA`) you are referring to was introduced with Excel 2013. Same for `FORMULATEXT`.

Comment: @Jeeped oh, man! I didn't realize `Formulatext` was 2013. ...Oh well. I think Scott posted an answer earlier with a formula (if OP can't use VBA) but deleted it, maybe he used `formulatext` too, I can't recall.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I used to footnote whenever I used AGGREGATE (introduced with Excel 2010) but now that 2010 seems to be the *de facto* standard, I've ceased adding that annotation.

Comment: Thanks guys, I can't do VBA. I'm a VBA programmer but the company will be using this as a standard formula users can use between excel documents so they refuse macro-enabled docs.

I have no solution at the moment so I used a work-around for my purpose. But I am really thankful for the suggestions :)

Comment: @jay - Does [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/360369/how-to-tell-if-an-excel-cell-has-a-formula-or-is-hardcoded) help any? The conditional formatting looks like it may work.

Comment: No sorry, my Excel 2010 does not have `FORMULATEXT()`

Answer (score 1):

The MrExcel website (link below) has this method which uses old code from Excel 4 (which is still present for backward compatibility)...

Define a NAME such as "CellToLeftHasFormula" and in the "refers to" box put

`=GET.CELL(48,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),0,-1))`

Then in column B use the formula =CellToLeftHasFormula which will return TRUE if it has.

Be aware that this will mean your Excel will now contain a macro and so will need to be saved as such (xlsm). I use this in Excel 2010.

For full explanation (and other .CELL options, besides 48) see MrExcel link: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/20611-info-only-get-cell-arguments.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Range.HasFormula property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasformula

EDIT:

Text and code from the above link:

*"True if all cells in the range contain formulas; False if none of the cells in the range contains a formula; null otherwise. Read-only Variant. ..."*

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
Set rr = Application.InputBox( _ 
    prompt:="Select a range on this worksheet", _ 
    Type:=8) 
If rr.HasFormula = True Then 
    MsgBox "Every cell in the selection contains a formula" 
End If
```

Comment: This is basically a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Try adding more explanation and possible some relevant code samples (even copied from the link would be useful)

Comment: I now notice that @BruceWayne has already mentioned the 'hasFormula' property.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the user by protecting the column A.

You can directly check if a cell contains a formula by using a shortcut **Ctrl + `**.

You can use vba and write a user defined function :
1. Press alt + F11
2. Insert module in workbook
3. Paste this code

```
Function IsFormula(cell_ref As Range) 
IsFormula = cell_ref.HasFormula 
End Function
```

4. Now, use Isformula in the cell wherever you want.